# Setting up web application on Ubuntu Server 12.04 results in Internal Server Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have an existing web application (currently working on Windows 7). I set up a box with Ubuntu Server 12.04 that I wish to host/test my application on. Problem is, when I try to access the app I get an 500 Internal Server Error.

To be sure there is something wrong with the app itself (as opposed to Ubuntu and Apache configurations) I set up a test domain on the Ubuntu Server which I can access from my windows computer without a problem. I then ftp'd the app to this folder.

This app is using Code Igniter. I have changed the config file to reflect any changes that may affect names/paths. I have a database that is set up correctly. Have I forgotten to change anything else that would cause this error when transferring from Windows to Ubuntu?

edit: As suggested by Steve V here is a message I get in my error log when trying to access the site.

[alert] [client xxx.xxx.x.x] THEPATH/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Could be a lot of things. See if there's anything in the apache error logs, maybe at /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite engine isn't enabled.
Go to shell and do the following:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks!! and thanks to Seven V too. I'm getting other errors but they're being displayed by ci so at least I can debug those easily.